# Use LspConfig root_dir in Neogit cwd

Tags: neovim, lua, lsp, git

I'm trying to setup Neogit to open in my workspace directory instead of cwd. The problem is that I use multi root workspaces, so I usually set my cwd to be `workspace1/..`. My initial try was to use something like this (I use NvChad):

```
M.neovim = {
  n = {
    ["<leader>gg"] = {
      function()
          local neovim = require("neogit");
          neovim.open({ cwd = vim.lsp.buf.list_workspace_folders()[0] })
      end,
      "Open Neogit in lsp cwd",
    },
  }
}
```

But that doesn't seem to do anything and Neogit uses `workspace1/..` anyway :/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming I don't change the workspace after launching vim.

```
M.neovim = {
  n = {
    ["<leader>gg"] = {
      function()
          local neovim = require("neogit");
          neovim.open({ cwd = vim.lsp.buf.list_workspace_folders()[1] })
      end,
      "Open Neogit in lsp cwd",
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post answers in the body of a question; post them down here as an answer instead. (Welcome to [vi.se]! The [help] has more information on our Q&A model.)